# How do I return the respective data to viewpager2 on an item clicked in a recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

I have list of data(departments) In a recycler view, when I clicked on item1 I now populate *four* semester fragments in MyViewPager2. How can I do for Item2 click to loads it specific semester fragments in a viewpager2.

Note:

On Item1 click worked fine, what of for item2? The comments illustrate every thing I need. Below is what I have. Thanks

MyViewPager2.java

```
package com.example.viewpager2;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;

public class MyViewPager2  extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    public MyViewPager2(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        //this returns Semester(position) but only the data for an item2 clicked in a recyclerview display
        // to me is like here, will return all data inside viewpager in their respective item clicked
        return new Semesters(position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 4;// i have changing this to 8 two but kept on inflate the same item Clicked
    }
}
```

DepartmentRVAdapter.java

```
package com.example.viewpager2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class DepartmentRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DepartmentRVAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    List<DepartmentModel> mData;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    ClickInterface clickInterface;
    DepartmentFragment departmentFragment;

    public DepartmentRVAdapter(List<DepartmentModel> mData, Context context, ClickInterface clickInterface, DepartmentFragment sf) {
        this.mData=mData;
        this.context=context;
        this.clickInterface=clickInterface;
        departmentFragment =sf;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_department_xml,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return vh;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.imgDepLogo.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getDepLogo());
        holder.tvDepName.setText(mData.get(position).getDepName());
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView imgDepLogo;
        TextView tvDepName;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgDepLogo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgDeptLogo);
            tvDepName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDepName);
            tvDepName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   clickInterface.onItemClickListener(getLayoutPosition());
                 switch (getAdapterPosition()){
                        //loads department best on the position that user click
                        case 0:
                        // it loads all departments in the school
                          Objects.requireNonNull(departmentFragment.getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager()
                                  .beginTransaction()
//                                  .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.exit_to_right)
                                  .replace(R.id.frameLayout,new SemesterFragment())
                                  .addToBackStack(null).
                                  commit();
                            break;
                            case 1:
                            // it loads all departments in the school
//                                Objects.requireNonNull(departmentFragment.getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager()
//                                        .beginTransaction()
//                                       // .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.exit_to_left,R.anim.enter_from_right,R.anim.exit_to_left)
//                                        .replace(R.id.frameLayout,new SemesterFragment())
//                                        .addToBackStack(null).
//                                        commit();
//                        break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

DepartmentFragment.java

```
package com.example.viewpager2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DepartmentFragment extends Fragment implements ClickInterface {
    List<DepartmentModel> mData;
    DepartmentRVAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public DepartmentFragment() {

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start,container,false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        mData = new ArrayList<>();
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        adapter = new DepartmentRVAdapter(mData,getContext(),this, DepartmentFragment.this);
        //list of departments in the school
        mData.add(new DepartmentModel("Computer Science",R.drawable.glogo));
        mData.add(new DepartmentModel("Statistic",R.drawable.horse));

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
    //here implement interface class methods
    @Override
    public void onItemClickListener(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"clicked " + mData.get(position).getDepName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    @Override
    public void onItemLongClickListener(int position) {

    }
}
```

Semesters.java

```
package com.example.viewpager2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Semesters extends Fragment{
    List<SemesterModelClass> mData;
    RVFragment adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public Semesters(int position) {
        mData = getList(position);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        adapter = new RVFragment(getContext(),mData);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
    //Note:
    //It worked perfect when the user click on ITEM1 (ONE) in the recyclerview.
    //What i want is for the ITEM2 (TWO) to do thesame
    private List<SemesterModelClass> getList(int position) {
        List<SemesterModelClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
            // onItem1 (one) clicked in a recyclerview,
            // these data are populated in their respective fragment in a viewpager2
        if (position == 0) {
            // this populate first semester fragment inside viewpager2
            // if the user click on item1 in a recyclerView
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem1", "com111", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem1", "com222", "5"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem1", "com121", "4"));
        } else if (position == 1) {
            // this populate second semester fragment inside viewpager2
            // if the user click on item1 in a recyclerView
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem2", "com111", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem2", "com222", "5"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem2", "com121", "4"));
        } else if (position == 2) {
            // this populate third semester fragment inside viewpager2
            // if the user click on item1 in a recyclerView
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem3", "com111", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem3", "com222", "5"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem3", "com121", "4"));
        } else {
            // this populate fourth semester fragment inside viewpager2
            // if the user click on item1 in a recyclerView
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem4", "com111", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem4", "com222", "5"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem4", "com121", "4"));
        }
        return list;
    }
    //***********************************************************************************************
    // onItem2 (two) clicked in a recyclerview,
    // i want to do thesame thing without creating another similar class like this

    private  List<SemesterModelClass>  getList(int position){
        List<SemesterModelClass> list = new ArrayList<>();

        if(position == 0) {
            // i want to populate first semester fragment inside viewpager2
            // if the user click on item2 (two) in a recyclerView
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem1 descriptive", "STA 111", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem1 set theory", "STA 112", "4"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem1 algebra", "STA 113", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem1 logic", "STA 114", "4"));
        }else if(position == 1) {
            // i want to populate second semester fragment inside viewpager2
            // if the user click on item2 (two) in a recyclerView
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem1 descriptive", "STA 111", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem1 set theory", "STA 112", "4"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem1 algebra", "STA 113", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem1 logic", "STA 114", "4"));
        }else if(position == 2) {
            // i want to populate third semester fragment inside viewpager2
            // if the user click on item2 (two) in a recyclerView
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem1 descriptive", "STA 111", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem1 set theory", "STA 112", "4"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem1 algebra", "STA 113", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem1 logic", "STA 114", "4"));
        }else{
            // i want to populate fourth semester fragment inside viewpager2
            // if the user click on item2 (two) in a recyclerView
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem1 descriptive", "STA 111", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem1 set theory", "STA 112", "4"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem1 algebra", "STA 113", "3"));
            list.add(new SemesterModelClass("sem1 logic", "STA 114", "4"));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

SemesterFragment.java

```
package com.example.viewpager2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator;

public class SemesterFragment extends Fragment{
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager2 viewPager2;
    MyViewPager2 adapter;

    public SemesterFragment() {

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_semester, container, false);
        viewPager2 = (ViewPager2) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager2);
        tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        adapter = new MyViewPager2(getChildFragmentManager(),this.getLifecycle());

        viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);
        new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2,
                new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                        tab.setText("Sem" + (position + 1));
                    }
                }).attach();
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any answer to this please??

Comment: As I understand, you need  have departments and each department have 4 semesters. When you click on any of the semester than it should open semester fragment. 
My question is why not use nested recycler view or expandable recycler view ( a bit tricky to implement but doable)?

Comment: @@mohammed that's not how i meant, I have departments in a recycler review, and when u click on any of the items then it opens a fragment (SemesterFragment.java,  i.e where viewpager2 and tab layout are initialize and linked) and then the MyViewPager2.java is an adapter that return Semester.java which holds 4 fragments embedded on each of the item clicked in the recycler view (departments). It's working fine but now for the other items, only for the  Item1 (computer science) clicked that is working. What for the item2(statistic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not adding fragments to your adopter. And it does not do it all by its own if we say getItemCount() returns 4.

Modify MyViewPager2.java, replace your CreateFragment method to some thing like.

```
   public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
   // the following should work but I would prefer to have more control over things so would use fragment list. 
   //return new Semesters(position);
   // like this
   return mSemestersList.get(position);
  }
```

Next you have to define a method to add fragments to your list.

```
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title ){
    this.mFragmentsList.add(fragment);
    this.mFragmentsTitleList.add(title);
}
```

Also return the size of mFragmentsList in your getItemCount method.

Finally call addFragment() in your SemesterFragment.java.

```
 adapter = new MyViewPager2(getChildFragmentManager(),this.getLifecycle());
 adapter.addFragment(new Semesters(1),"Fall Semester 1");
 // and so on for all four semesters.
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort,but I have tried something like this it couldn't work.

Comment: It does thesame thing but only when I click on the first Item in a DepartmentRVAdapder.java, it populates 4 fragy only for the item clicked. I want it that if u also click on Item2 then populate another 4 frags but respectively as the their data is different. Thanks, Mohammed

Comment: Someone please help answer this question