# Items click from recycler view to viewpager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

I have a fragment that has list of items in a recycler view. When I clicked on **Item1** In the recycler view then I was able to open a viewpager that has container holding 4 fragments that has different data such as data1,data2...data4.

My want to achieve now is, if I click also on **Item2** I should open a viewpager container holding 2 fragments with different data such as semester 1 and semester 2.

Please someone help,upto a week now trying to find a solution but I couldn't.  Thanks

The link below

[How do I return the respective data to viewpager2 on an item clicked in a recycler view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67094950/how-do-i-return-the-respective-data-to-viewpager2-on-an-item-clicked-in-a-recycl/67121914#67121914)

Comment: I'm afraid your text description it's not very helpful. Please provide images/videos of what you have so far or of the result you want to achieve.

Comment: I will provide but please here for me

Comment: Here is the link @ Ornelas <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67094950/how-do-i-return-the-respective-data-to-viewpager2-on-an-item-clicked-in-a-recycl/67121914#67121914>

Comment: I don't get it. Is that your code?

Comment: Yes sir that's my code